# How to refresh only button text in jquery ui diaolog components

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, popup, updatepanel, jquery-ui-dialog

I have jQueryUI dialog(popup). There are some controls on it. I will enter data, then           I will click btnFindPerson and will refresh btnAddNewPerson text. But, btnAddNewPerson text  could not not refresh without closing popup

Script:

```
    function x() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
            open: function (type, data) { $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); },
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="Button" name="name" title="ccc" value=" bbb" onclick="x();" />
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFindPerson" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger  ControlID="btnAddNewPerson"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="dialog" style="display: none;">
            This is a simple popup
            <asp:Label Text="Ara:" runat="server" ID="x" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEnterPerson" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnFindPerson" Text="Bul" runat="server" OnClick="btnFindPerson_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewPerson" Text="Yeni Kişi Ekle" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this so confusing...
Use Ajax request, change it to a simple client side `input` and you won't need the buggy UpdatePanel and Postbacks.